# Placing figures adjacent to exam choices

Tags: floats, lists, minipage, exam

In the following mwe, I'd like the circular ohm formula figure to be positioned further to the right and the bottom of the figure lined up with choice D of question 4. I don't want the blank space between the questions. Moving the `\includegraphics` command without and within the list environment does odd things too.

I've tried

```
\newlength{\oldparindent} \setlength{\oldparindent}{\parindent}% Save   \parindent
\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.17\textwidth]{ohm_law}}% Original image
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.17\textwidth}
\raisebox{-\ht0}{\usebox0}% Insert image
\end{minipage}
```

which I found somewhere. It brings the figure to the right, spaces the questions apart, leaving whitespace at the left. I believe the solution is minipage but how?

Here is the mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[scaled=1.05,proportional,lightcondensed]{zlmtt}
\usepackage{graphicx} %needed to include pictures (png)
\usepackage{tabularx}%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be typewriter style

\extraheadheight[-1.25in]{-0.25in}
\extrafootheight{-1in}
\begin{document}

%\printanswers    %uncomment and re-compile to print answer key

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\lhead{}
\chead[]{Electrical Systems 20 Exam(continued)}
\rhead{}

\title{Electrical Systems 20 \\\textsc{Exam}}
\date{}
\maketitle
\textsc{NAME}\enspace\makebox[3in]{\hrulefill}
\textsc{DATE}\enspace\makebox[1.5in]{\hrulefill}
\fullwidth{}
\vspace{0.1in}
%\fullwidth{\large \textbf{1) Multiple Choices}}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
\textsc {Choose the \emph{most correct} answer from the choices given.}}}}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.1in}

\begin{questions}
\boxedpoints
\pointsinrightmargin
\question[1]Automotive wiring diagrams include
\begin{choices}
\choice A series of colour coded diagrams
\choice Specific symbols to identify components
\choice Wire gauge sizes
\correctchoice All of the above
\end{choices}

\question[1]When soldering an electrical connection, use
\begin{choices}
\choice Acid core flux
\correctchoice Rosin core flux
\choice A or B
\choice Neither A or B
\end{choices}

\question[1]An electrical component that allows current to flow in one
direction only is called
\begin{choices}
\choice Watt
\choice Anode
\choice Cathode
\CorrectChoice Diode
\end{choices}


\question[1]Ohm's law states that
\includegraphics[width=2.0cm]{ohm_law} %started with this
\begin{choices}
\choice $1\ volt = 1\ amp \times 1 \Omega$
\choice $1\ amp = \frac{1\ volt}{1 \Omega}$
\choice $1 \Omega = \frac{1\ volt}{1\ amp}$
\CorrectChoice All of the above are true.
\end{choices}

\question[1] In a parallel circuit,
\begin{choices}
\choice the voltage is the same throughout the circuit, but the
current is divided.
\choice The total circuit resistance is always less than the smallest
resistor in the circuit.
\choice there is more than one path for current to flow.
\CorrectChoice All of the above are true.
\end{choices}

\question[1] An electronic device which acts like a high speed switch
is a
\begin{choices}
\choice triode
\choice diode
\choice monode
\correctchoice transistor
\end{choices}

\end{questions}
\end{document} here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a macro like:

```
\newcommand\myimage[2][width=2cm]{%
\hfill\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
}
```

and use it like

```
\question[1]Ohm's law states that\myimage[width=3cm]{example-image}
\begin{choices}
\choice $1\ volt = 1\ amp \times 1 \Omega$
\choice $1\ amp = \frac{1\ volt}{1 \Omega}$
\choice $1 \Omega = \frac{1\ volt}{1\ amp}$
\CorrectChoice All of the above are true.
\end{choices}
```

[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[scaled=1.05,proportional,lightcondensed]{zlmtt}
\usepackage{graphicx} %needed to include pictures (png)
\usepackage{tabularx}%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be typewriter style

\extraheadheight[-1.25in]{-0.25in}
\extrafootheight{-1in}

\newcommand\myimage[2][width=2cm]{%
\hfill\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
}
\begin{document}

%\printanswers    %uncomment and re-compile to print answer key

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\lhead{}
\chead[]{Electrical Systems 20 Exam(continued)}
\rhead{}

\title{Electrical Systems 20 \\\textsc{Exam}}
\date{}
\maketitle
\textsc{NAME}\enspace\makebox[3in]{\hrulefill}
\textsc{DATE}\enspace\makebox[1.5in]{\hrulefill}
\fullwidth{}
\vspace{0.1in}
%\fullwidth{\large \textbf{1) Multiple Choices}}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
\textsc {Choose the \emph{most correct} answer from the choices given.}}}}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.1in}

\begin{questions}
\boxedpoints
\pointsinrightmargin
\question[1]Automotive wiring diagrams include
\begin{choices}
\choice A series of colour coded diagrams
\choice Specific symbols to identify components
\choice Wire gauge sizes
\correctchoice All of the above
\end{choices}

\question[1]When soldering an electrical connection, use
\begin{choices}
\choice Acid core flux
\correctchoice Rosin core flux
\choice A or B
\choice Neither A or B
\end{choices}

\question[1]An electrical component that allows current to flow in one
direction only is called
\begin{choices}
\choice Watt
\choice Anode
\choice Cathode
\CorrectChoice Diode
\end{choices}


\question[1]Ohm's law states that\myimage[width=3cm]{example-image}
%\hfill\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=3.0cm]{example-image}}} %started with this}
\begin{choices}
\choice $1\ volt = 1\ amp \times 1 \Omega$
\choice $1\ amp = \frac{1\ volt}{1 \Omega}$
\choice $1 \Omega = \frac{1\ volt}{1\ amp}$
\CorrectChoice All of the above are true.
\end{choices}

\question[1] In a parallel circuit,
\begin{choices}
\choice the voltage is the same throughout the circuit, but the
current is divided.
\choice The total circuit resistance is always less than the smallest
resistor in the circuit.
\choice there is more than one path for current to flow.
\CorrectChoice All of the above are true.
\end{choices}

\question[1] An electronic device which acts like a high speed switch
is a
\begin{choices}
\choice triode
\choice diode
\choice monode
\correctchoice transistor
\end{choices}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

As a side note, please consider using `siunitx` package for type setting units. There is it easy typing units like `\SI{1}{\ampere}` and spacing is all correct.